# Simplifying an integral involving Von Mises distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Is there any way to simplify or approximate the following integral?
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi log\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi f_{VM}(x; s, \kappa)p(s)ds\right)f_{VM}(x; s, \kappa)dx$$
where $f_{VM}$ is the von Mises probability density function with mean $\mu$ and concentration parameter $\kappa$, and $p(s)$ is an unknown probability density function.

For a special case when $p(s)$ is also a von Mises, I managed to simplify it slightly:
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi log\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi f_{VM}(x; s, \kappa)f_{VM}(s; \mu_s, \kappa_s)ds\right)f_{VM}(x; s, \kappa)dx=\\
\int_{-\pi}^\pi log\left(I_{0}(\sqrt{\kappa^2 +\kappa_s^2+2\kappa\kappa_s\cos(x-\mu_s)})\right)f_{VM}(x; s, \kappa)dx-log(2\pi I_{0}(\kappa)I_{0}(\kappa_s))$$
with $I_{0}$ being the modified Bessel function of the first kind, zero order.
But even in this case, I wasn't able to get further than that.

I was also thinking of using normal instead of von Mises assuming that $\kappa$ is sufficiently high, but I'm not sure if it would be helpful.

Any hints would be appreciated!